# AngularJS http action executes multiple foreign event

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I made a simple function to handle update actions for user. A simple form that look like this

```
<div class="com-md-12 col-sm-12 no-pad no-margine" ng-controller="ProfileCtrl" ng-init="getProfile('{{$safeID}}')">
{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal signup-form', 'ng-submit' => 'updateProfile($event)')) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            {!! Form::text('first_name', old('first_name'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'First Name*', 'ng-model' => 'uProfile.first_name')); !!}
            {!! MessagerService::setInlineError($errors->first('first_name')) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            {!! Form::text('last_name', old('last_name'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Last Name*', 'ng-model' => 'uProfile.last_name')); !!}
            {!! MessagerService::setInlineError($errors->first('last_name')) !!}
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            {!! Form::text('username', old('username'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Screen Name*', 'ng-model' => 'uProfile.username')); !!}
            {!! MessagerService::setInlineError($errors->first('username')) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            {!! Form::text('dob', old('dob'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'dob', 'placeholder' => 'Date of Birth*', 'ng-model' => 'uProfile.dob')); !!}
            {!! MessagerService::setInlineError($errors->first('dob')) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                {!! Form::select('gender', ['' => '------ Gender ------', 'male' => 'Male', 'female' => 'Female'], old('gender'), 
            array('class' => 'form-control', 'ng-model' => 'uProfile.gender')) !!}
            {!! MessagerService::setInlineError($errors->first('gender')) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="p_url_pretext">example.com/</span>
            {!! Form::text('profile_url', old('profile_url'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Profile URL*', 'ng-model' => 'uProfile.profile_url')); !!}
            </div>  
            {!! MessagerService::setInlineError($errors->first('profile_url')) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default cbtn-login" style="float: right;">Save updates</button>
        </div>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

with angular script that look like this

```
$scope.updateProfile = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : svrid('www') + '/ws/profile/update',
        data    : $.param($scope.uProfile),  // pass in data as strings
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

Everything worked as i expected but I have noticed 1 weird behavior. Why are there so many unrecognized requests before my final POST action is being executed?

I noticed that supposed my action route is `http://www.example.com:8000/ws/profile/update` it somehow keeps on calling `http://www.example.com:8000/ws/profile` with 3 different requests `POST`, `GET`, and `DELETE` before it finally reaches the intended request as shown in image below

[image]

Anyone have any idea what causes such behavior to happen or have I coded something wrong in anywhere that leads to such incident?

**Update 1:** Here is the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gLGwdzPKK24dCpUCl1F8) file. Noted that i could not re-simulate the error because the site is currently at `localhost`

**Update 2:** I have narrowed down that the `ng-init="getProfile('{{$safeID}}')` might have been causing this problem. I tried removing that line and give it a constant value and the errors do not appear. What's with such behavior?

Comment: can you create a plunkr ?

Comment: @ngLover im still new to this. give me some time... i'll try and once done i'll update the post.

Comment: @ngLover I've updated the post. See if it help you to understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the problem that causes such behavior. It is mainly because of the jQuery's `$.param` function. What really happens is the $.param operation will run through all properties of you object. Using $.param as the object will not automatically convert to a url encoded string (though I think it should).

So what I as a workaround to this problem is create a manual serialization function like such

```
function serializeData( data ) {
    // If this is not an object, defer to native stringification.
    if ( ! angular.isObject( data ) ) {
        return( ( data == null ) ? "" : data.toString() );
    }
    var buffer = [];

    // Serialize each key in the object.
    for ( var name in data ) {
        if ( ! data.hasOwnProperty( name ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        var value = data[ name ];
        buffer.push(
            encodeURIComponent( name ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( ( value == null ) ? "" : value )
        );
    }

    // Serialize the buffer and clean it up for transportation.
    var source = buffer.join( "&" ).replace( /%20/g, "+" );
    return( source );
}
```

pass the form payload to the serialization function then append it into angular's #http

```
    $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : svrid('www') + '/ws/profile/update',
            data    : serializeData($scope.uProfile),  // pass in data as strings
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.uError = null;
        }).error(function(data) {
            $scope.uError = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
```

and everything works like a charm.